# $http patch method returns bad request in Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using angularJS and Spring MVC, and I can't the PATCH request I want to, when I try the response is a Bad Request.

SpringController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/patients")
public class PatientController {

    private class PatientRace {
        private String race;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public void updatePatientRace(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody PatientRace patientRace) {
        System.out.println(id + ", " + patientRace.race);
    }
}
```

Request being made in AngularJS using $http module:

```
$http.patch(href, {race: 'Something'})
    .then(function(response) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
```

If anyone could help me I would be really thankfull.

Thank you

Comment: what is the value of `href'?

Comment: Additional information that might be useful if included in the question: the full, server-side stack trace; the model (i.e. `PatientRace`)

Comment: @DeendayalGarg - The value of href is link http://localhost:8080/api/patients/2222, for example.

Comment: it looks correct. does you `PatientRace` contains any other fields? Do you have JSON to Pojo convertor configured?

Comment: PatientRace does not contain other fields. Probably missing JSON to Pojo convertor, but I don't know what that is. Can you provide some link please?

Comment: I knew what was wrong. The class PatientRace had to be static, changed that and it worked. Thank you for the comments.